# Solr /admin/luke requests sometimes return nulls

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I'm trying to get some metadata (document count and last modified date) from Solr, and found `/solr/<core>/admin/luke` endpoint to do it.

However, my requests sometimes return nulls instead of values. I can reproduce it via both SolrJ and curl:

> ✗ curl hostname/solr/core_name/admin/luke -s | jq '.index.lastModified'
>
> "2019-06-04T19:59:45.617Z"
>
> ✗ curl hostname/solr/core_name/admin/luke -s | jq '.index.lastModified'
>
> null

Without `jq` results are either:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2},
  "index":{
    "numDocs":11,
    "maxDoc":11,
    "deletedDocs":0,
    "indexHeapUsageBytes":-1,
    "version":6,
    "segmentCount":1,
    "current":true,
    "hasDeletions":false,
    "directory":"org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory:NRTCachingDirectory(MMapDirectory@ ... lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@2846d2cf; maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0)",
    "segmentsFile":"segments_1",
    "segmentsFileSizeInBytes":-1,
    "userData":{
      "commitTimeMSec":"1559730066881",
      "commitCommandVer":"1635495514608762880"},
    "lastModified":"2019-06-05T10:21:06.881Z"},
  "fields":{ .... },
  "info":{ .... }
}
```

or:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2},
  "index":{
    "numDocs":11,
    "maxDoc":11,
    "deletedDocs":0,
    "indexHeapUsageBytes":-1,
    "version":4,
    "segmentCount":1,
    "current":false,
    "hasDeletions":false,
    "directory":"org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory:NRTCachingDirectory(MMapDirectory@ .... lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@1e10c435; maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0)",
    "segmentsFile":"segments_1",
    "segmentsFileSizeInBytes":-1,
    "userData":{}},
  "fields":{ .... },
  "info":{ .... }
}
```

I've omitted part of `index.directory`, `fields` and `info`. The difference is in `version`, `current`, `userData` and `lastModified`, everything else looks the same.

I'm using Solr 7.5 in Cloud mode. My collections are on multiple shards with replicas = 2 (or more). I've tried adding `?numTerms=50` to request, but it doesn't help.

Is there something I can do to always receive correct response?

Comment: What is the actual result of the curl call when you're getting a `null` from `jq`?

Comment: @MatsLindh I've edited it in!

Comment: `"segmentsFileSizeInBytes":-1,` seems to indicate that Solr is unable to read the files when you're asking - are the actual index files stored directly on a physical disk, or are they hosted over NFS/HDFS/docker mountpoint/etc.?

Comment: Turn your log level to `DEBUG` to see all log entries - the cases where Solr can return -1 [should generate a WARN or DEBUG message](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/77a4bfaa90637cd3d9a8a2ef4889e163dab143aa/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/admin/LukeRequestHandler.java#L621): This should at least give you a hint to why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

`.index.lastModified` is calculated from `.index.userData.commitTimeMSec` by the Luke Request Handler. That's why the last three digits are always the same.

If your core hasn't had any commits yet, `.index.userData` is empty and Luke simply doesn't add `.index.lastModified` to the response. That's what you're seeing on your second request.

From [LukeRequestHandler.java](https://github.com/apache/solr/blob/f6d60c375cdabfbd6d5e17b4050db362eb4dbff4/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/admin/LukeRequestHandler.java#L593-L596):

```java
String s = userData.get(SolrIndexWriter.COMMIT_TIME_MSEC_KEY);
if (s != null) {
  indexInfo.add("lastModified", new Date(Long.parseLong(s)));
}
```